# Dependency management for Android projects with bitbucket

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket, dependency-management

I am an iOS developer who started learning android recently.  When writing iOS apps in an enterprise environment, I use cocoapod to manage dependency between several projects.  I know that Android Studio uses gradle to manage dependency.  But how can I configure it to use an enterprise bitbucket repo?  I would like it to download the source code locally like cocoapod rather than using aar files.  Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I found it out myself.  It is possible to add git commands by grgit or just [“git” “checkout” “......”].execute.

Comment: Please provide a clear explanation with proper code